# How to remove records from a table where data in some column matches with same in another identical table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two tables **Table1** and **Table2**. Both of these tables have the same structure. All I want to do is to remove those records from **Table1** for which the value in two columns (say A and B) both are same as in **Table2**.

So, if there is a record in **Table2** where the value of A and B are 12 and 24 respectively, the record(s) in **Table1** containing the same values in those respective columns needs to be deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below query :

```
DELETE FROM Table1
WHERE EXISTS
(
  SELECT 1 FROM Table2 WHERE Table1.A = Table2.A AND Table1.B = Table2.B 
)
```

Comment: What if I use "SELECT * FROM" instead of "SELECT 1 FROM" in the subquery? Will it delete multiple same occurrences?

Comment: No It is just for exists or not.

Comment: Ok.. I think the query would be more like--                                                                           
SELECT 1 FROM Table2 t2 join Table1 t1 ON t1.A = t2.A AND t1.B = t2.B

Answer (score 1):

```
DELETE FROM table1, table2 WHERE table1.A = table2.A AND table1.B = table2.B
```

DELETE command deletes all the records in the specified table(s) by default.
So we have to add a WHERE clause, telling the query to act on particular columns A and B, both present in table1 and table2.
We can reference to a column of a particular table using the "dot notation":

```
table_name.column_name
```

You can put any condition here, like "is equal to", "is not equal to", "is lesser than", "is greater than", etc..., as long as is correct and makes sense for the query. So, we just add:

```
table1.A = table2.A
```

Multiple conditions can be combined using logical operators, like AND, OR and XOR. So, as your question is saying, values in column A and B must be equal, so we add another condition, joining them with the AND operator, because all of the two conditions must be true!

Comment: But, wouldn't it delete the record(s) from both of the tables (both Table1 and Table2)?  I just want the records to be deleted from Table1, not from Table2.

Comment: Ok, so just remove the ", table2" from the tale list after the FROM